# WheelCollider not working using Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

i have simple 3D car, which has wheel `colliders`. Now I am using below written script and assigning them `colliders` but when i run my game nothing happens

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CarMoves : MonoBehaviour {

    public WheelCollider wheelFL;
    public WheelCollider wheelFR;
    public WheelCollider wheelBL;
    public WheelCollider wheelBR;
    float Maxtorque = 50;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        wheelBR.motorTorque = Maxtorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        wheelBL.motorTorque = Maxtorque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        wheelFL.steerAngle = 10 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        wheelFR.steerAngle = 10 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    }

}
```

all these public `colliders` are attached through unity inspector

Comment: is it not turning or not moving at all?

Comment: when i run they penetrate through terrain collider or fly upwards

Comment: I think your axes may be mixed up......what axes do you want to move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the mass on the rigidbody on the car base is at least 1000kg.

Also the wheel colliders suspension spring to 12000+ and damper to roughly 2000